# Microsoft Teams Graph API - Create Team without Group ID

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to integrate ServiceNow with the Microsoft Teams API via the IntegrationHub. I am receiving an error stating the GroupId is not valid.

From my understanding of Microsoft Teams and Office 365 the GUID is "A Guid that is the unique identifier for the object; for example, 12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcde12. Key. Not nullable. Read-only.".

This is not something which will be available, and I wanted to know if there is a possibility to create a teams group via the API without provide a GUID?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create a team without using group id in beta version. Could you please go through the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Nikitha-MSFT. I have read the docs previously and it references creating the group via templates and userId. Is that what you are referencing, and have you used it previously?

Comment: Could you please go through the docs which i have provided.It allows to create a team without using any user id.